# How to determine the K and T values of a modified PID controller?

Tags: transfer-function, pid-controller

[image: Equationstrong text][Circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQp3e.png)

I need to determine the K and T values for the given circuit. I hope I‘ve got the correct equation but I don‘t know how do I have to modify it get the parameters. Can I bring T_R1 & T_R2 and T_N1 & T_N2 together?

Comment: there is also latex and matjax, that would be a better format to post equations. There is also a built in circuit editor if you edit your questions